# What is the difference? Sentence B sounds odd when you read it

Tags: grammar, tense

Sentence A: I have come from a place that is a long way away from here. Sentence B: I am come from a place that is a long way away from here.

Answer (score 1):

"I am come” is archaic, and is not considered to be a grammatically correct sentence based on the rules of modern English. No one would ever talk like that. That's something you would find only if you dug old English works of literature. The correct form in this case is: "I have come."

Comment: I understand your point about archaic English, but yet I have a feeling that (B) expresses something that (A) doesn't. Isn't it the case that (B) has a greater equivalence with: I hail from a country that is a long way away from here?

Comment: (B) doesn't really express anything at all because nobody will understand what you're saying.

Comment: Okay, I am persuaded that (B) is old-fashioned, and there is no justification for it to be used in today's English.

Comment: "Isn't it the case that (B) has a greater equivalence with: I hail from a country that is a long way away from here?" No, that would be "I come from a place that is a long way away from here".

Comment: By and large, my question has been answered, and I am indebted to everyone for their contribution. One final thought: I keep thinking, perhaps mistakenly, that (B), among other things, is also trying to say something of my origin, the place I originate from.

Answer (score -1):

Sentence B sounds odd because it's incorrect. **Come** is a verb. You can say:

> I come from a place...
>
> I came from a place...
>
> I have come from a place...
>
> I am coming from a place...

etc.

You cannot say "I am come." That's wrong.

Comment: Lear: When we are born, we cry that we are come. Have a look at this sentence. How do you explain this, if what you say be true?

Comment: Thats an archaic perfect tense.  It's valid in early modern English,  not today.